# Unity - Autoresize with Abn sprite manager 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I'm building a 2d game and I am using sprite scripts from anb soft. I am trying to build for iphone tall res, but the simulator gets the max resolution of 640 * 865 instead of 640 * 960, so i can't really position the elements on the screen. Because pixel perfect is checked,auotresize is also checked and this generates problems. The monitor it set to the max res available.
Any ideas?